# Netbeans Clean and Build not ending

Tags: java, maven, svn, netbeans, compilation

I'm checking out a svn project. Afterwards I want to run the option "Clean & Build" in Netbeans (it's a maven project). But somehow, this takes forever and does not get finished when it's at the point of "Compiling 160 source files to [...]".

I already tried deleting and checking out the project again, as well as a complete reinstall of netbeans. On my notebook at my work place it's working fine.

Does anyone have an idea why this takes an infinite amount of time or has a suggestion what I can do?

[image: State of the clean and build where it hangs up]

Comment: I don't know a solution, but maybe try to build the project with maven from command line once? Depending on if that works or not you'll also know if your problem is actually related to Netbeans.

Comment: Have you tried to run that on command line instead from inside Netbeans?

Comment: try looking in the IDE's log for exception stacktraces..